# Backward stable algorithm to get orthogonal projection onto the column space of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-analysis, matrix, least-squares, projection

I have to find the orthogonal projection of a vector $b$ onto the matrix $A$ of size $m \times n$.

In my application, I don't have the luxury of calculating the QR factorization. All I have are routines that give me the least squares solutions with minimum norm, i.e., ${A^\dagger b}$. I can, of course, use matrix multiplication. There are two ways to get $\mbox{proj}_{A}(b)$, $A (A^{\dagger}b)$ or $(A^T)^{\dagger}(A^Tb)$.

What would be the better strategy for following cases in terms of backward stability?

1. $m>n$ and A is full rank.
2. $m>n$ and A is not full rank.
3. $n>m$ and A is not full rank.
4. $n=1$.

For the last part, [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5010/backward-stable-projection-and-normalization-of-a-vector) suggests that there is no backward stable algorithm on the account of the solution having an outer product. I am not convinced, though, because we never explicitly calculate the outer product.

Comment: Pleas define "least squares solutions with minimum norm".

Comment: I also think that that part of the answer you quote is not correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "all I have are routines that give me [...] $A^\dagger b$"? There are many ways to compute this solution, with different stability properties: QR, normal equations, SVD, gradient descent...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni You are right. Edited.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Could you direct me to some literature where gradient descent is used to solve $x = A^\dagger b$? In my application, I don't have an option of factorizing matrices.

Comment: @AbhayGupta I don't have a specific reference to suggest, but you'll find some material if you google for least squares and gradient descent (or stochastic gradient descent, a common variant).

Comment: My point is that for rank-deficient matrices, we will get multiple solutions for least squares problem. $A^{\dagger}$ gives the least squares solution which will have the minimum norm. I don't think gradient descent will give me this solution.