# Stable Method of orthogonal projection onto a subspace with the help of Moore-Penrose inverse,

Tags: numerical-analysis, least-squares, projection, matrix-factorization

Projection of a vector $v$ onto the column space of a matrix $A$ is given by $AA^\dagger v$. From the [definition of Moore-Penrose Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Definition) we know that $AA^\dagger v = (A^T)^\dagger A^T v $.

Below is the code for implementing the projection of a random vector onto the space of a random matrix. This is related to my other question [Backward stable algorithm to get orthogonal projection onto the column space of a matrix](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28754/backward-stable-algorithm-to-get-orthogonal-projection-onto-the-column-space-of). I didn't get an answer to that question.

I would like to know why is there a huge difference between the two methods of calculating the projection.

```
  % testingprojfrostackexchange
  clear;    
  M = 1400;
  N = 1300;
  r = 1;
  A = rand(M,N);
  u = rand(M,r);

  projLN = pinv(A')*(A'*u);%This is projection through Least Norm
  projLS = A*(pinv(A)*u);%This is projection through Least Square

  [Q R] = qr(A);
  Q = Q(:,1:N);
  z1 = Q*(Q'*u);%This is the actual projection

  display('(projection through QQT) - projLS');
  norm(z1-projLN)/norm(projLN)

  display('(projection through QQT) - projLN');
  norm(z1-projLS)/norm(projLS)
```

Output

```
>> stackexchange
   (projection through QQT) - projLS

   ans =

   2.1569e-13

   (projection through QQT) - projLN

   ans =

   8.3546e-15
```

The actual projection which is given by $Q(:,1:N)Q(:,1:N)^T$, where $Q$ is from the Housholder decomposition of $A$. We get the projections from $AA^\dagger$ and $(A^T)^\dagger A^T$ and find that $AA^\dagger$ is much better when $A$ is a tall matrix.